# How do I type asian quotation marks with mozc?

Tags: special-characters, mozc

I'm a Japanese learner and I have mozc installed on my PC. I can type hiragana, katakana, kanji and Japanese punctuation (at least 。, 、and ー), but I can't figure out how to type the Asian quotations marks : 「…」,『…』,〈…〉,《…》,
﹁
…
﹂
and
﹃
…
﹄.

(It might be usefull to also provide with details for other input methods)

Comment: https://eastasiastudent.net/china/mac-type-chinese-quotation-marks/

Comment: Tried what they say and it appears that [ and ] give 「 and 」. That's all I found, but that's not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

z[ and z] give 『and』

Read the Tofugu article: [how to type in Japanese](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/how-to-type-in-japanese/) for more info.

Comment: It would be better to directly indicate a link to the ressource you recommend.